# Set ipython as default interpreter in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I happen to experiment with Emacs for Python coding. I'd tried to change the default interpreter with Anaconda's ipython by the following ways in `.emacs`:

```
(setq python-python-command "~/anaconda2/bin/ipython")
```

or

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
```

but neither works.

Besides, when I switch to ipython directly (in Emacs shell or invoke it in C-c C-c) the prompt is messed up like this (the situation is the same in the Emacs shell in general):

```
^[[J^[[?7h^[[?12l^
```

How can I repair this phenomenon?

Comment: I have no experience with emacs, but maybe you should specify the full path?